# Send email with information from active line

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am trying to build a macro in Excel to send email with content from an active line (for example, clicking on a line, selecting all its content).

I need to take the email address from a cell on that line and assign it to the email To field.
The Subject field should have a title and adding at its end data from a cell on selected line.
In the body, I need to include content from selected line.
Before every selected cells' content, I need to enter a title.

Can I directly send an email through Excel, or is it possible to send the email by opening Outlook and having all the data ready using the macro?

Here's what is displayed in a spreadsheet:

```
FirstName LastName PhoneNumber
Dan       Daniels  123
Jim       Jameson  321
```

If the second line is the selected line, the email should look like this:

```
To: email@email.com
Subject: Random text - Dan Daniels
Body:

Hello,

FirstName: Dan
LastName: Daniels
PhoneNumber: 123
```

Here is the code I modified and gives me compiling error:

```
Sub SendMail()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object: Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim var As Variant: var = Selection.Value
    Set MyMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    With MyMail
        .To = var(1, 35)
        .Subject = "Email for Random Text Text Text Here -" & " " & var(1, 17) & " " & var(1, 18)
        .body = "This is an email informing you that random text aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Created by: " & var(1, 4) & vbNewLine & "Date Information Posted: " & var(1, 6) & vbNewLine & "Random Data One Showing: " & var(1, 28) & vbNewLine & "Another Random Data: " & var(1, 29) & vbNewLine & "Requester Random First Name: " & var(1, 13) & vbNewLine & "Requester Random Last Name: " & var(1, 14) & vbNewLine & "Requester Random Here E-mail: " & var(1, 15) & vbNewLine & "Requester Random Phone Number: " & var(1, 16) & vbNewLine & "Person's Random First Name: " & var(1, 17) & vbNewLine & "Person's Random Last Name: " & var(1, 18) & vbNewLine & "Person's Random Location: " & var(1, 21)  & vbNewLine & "Person's Random Occupation: " & var(1, 22) & vbNewLine & "Person's Random Hometown: " & var(1, 23) & vbNewLine & "Where he is located: " & var(1, 24) & vbNewLine & "PErson's Email Address: " & var(1, 19) & vbNewLine & "Number of items requested: " & var(1, 8) & vbNewLine & "Requested Items Number: " & var(1, 31) & vbNewLine & "Name of Item: " & var(1, 22) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This is a random text I need to add at the end of the mail, text being quite looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog random text random text random text random text random text random text"
    End With
    MyMail.send
End Sub
```

The data from columns are simple characters, names, numbers or email addresses. I have 35 columns, but need just the above ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would recommend a third column with the e-mail of the person.

Let's assume that you've agreed to add that. Your data would look something like:

```
FirstName LastName PhoneNumber Email
Dan       Daniels  123         Dan.Daniels@HisCompany.com
```

We would create an Outlook application object (using late binding)

```
Dim OutlookApp As Object: Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

and now we would need to fill in the properties of a MyMail object that we're going to create off Outlook. We're using to select instead of the active cell.

```
 Dim var as variant: var = selection.value 
 Set MyMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
```

Filling properties now:

```
      With MyMail
                .To = var(1,4)
                .Subject = "Random Text" &" "& var(1,1) & " " & var(1,2)
                .body = "Hello," & vbNewLine & "First name: " & var(1, 1) & vbNewLine & "Last Name: " & var(1, 1) & vbNewLine & "Phone number: " & var(1, 2)
            End With
```

We'll send this by using the send method of our MyMail object.

```
            MyMail.send
```

**Edit**: Here's the code of the full sub. I tested it and it works.

```
Sub SendMail()
Dim OutlookApp As Object: Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim var As Variant: var = Selection.Value
Set MyMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
          With MyMail
                    .To = var(1, 4)
                    .Subject = "Random Text" & " " & var(1, 1) & " " & var(1, 2)
                    .body = "Hello," & vbNewLine & "First name: " & var(1, 1) & vbNewLine & "Last Name: " & var(1, 2) & vbNewLine & "Phone number: " & var(1, 3)
                End With
                MyMail.send
End Sub
```

Pre-conditions:

Select the line prior to running the macro. Here's a preview of my data:

[image]

My Outlook outbox:

[image]

**Edit1**: Here's the correct `.body` property:

```
.body = "This is an email informing you that random text aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Created by: " & Var(1, 4) & vbNewLine & "Date Information Posted: " & Var(1, 6) & vbNewLine & "Random Data One Showing: " & Var(1, 28) & vbNewLine & "Another Random Data: " & Var(1, 29) & vbNewLine & _
"Requester Random First Name: " & Var(1, 13) & vbNewLine & "Requester Random Last Name: " & Var(1, 14) & vbNewLine & "Requester Random Here E-mail: " & Var(1, 15) & vbNewLine & "Requester Random Phone Number: " & Var(1, 16) & vbNewLine & "Person's Random First Name: " & Var(1, 17) & vbNewLine & "Person's Random Last Name: " & Var(1, 18) & vbNewLine & "Person's Random Location: " & Var(1, 21) & vbNewLine & "Person's Random Occupation: " & _
Var(1, 22) & vbNewLine & "Person's Random Hometown: " & Var(1, 23) & vbNewLine & "Where he is located: " & Var(1, 24) & vbNewLine & "PErson's Email Address: " & Var(1, 19) & vbNewLine & "Number of items requested: " & Var(1, 8) & vbNewLine & "Requested Items Number: " & Var(1, 31) & vbNewLine & "Name of Item: " & Var(1, 22) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"This is a random text I need to add at the end of the mail, text being quite looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog random text random text random text random text random text random text"
```

Comment: Thank you! I am a started at these kind of things, however I assume I will have to create this macro in the macro tool in Excel. Regarding the data, I have more than 3 columns, I just added those as an example, so that I may expand the code for the rest of it. I will try some things with the code you provided, and get back to see how I can handle it. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem @DantèsCristo! We'll figure it out together! :)

Comment: I tried creating a Macro in VDB, however when trying to save the exact code you provided me with, it gives me this error: The following Features cannot be saved in a macro-free workbooks:

VB Project

To save a file with these features, click no, and then choose a macro-enabled file type in the File Type list. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I enabled macros.

Comment: Let me try this on my pc.

Comment: Thanks again, it seems it works if I do not close my excel. I a close it, it gives me that error before saving. I am not able to save the VB project. It keeps showing me that error. I am not sure how to fully enable macro's. I think this might be some administrator restrictions. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Hm. You need to change the extension of your Excel spreadsheet to xlsm from the save dialog box! @DantèsCristo

Comment: It seems that it works, as I just needed to save the document as macro enabled spreadsheet. How do I proceed if I have more than 4 columns? I have about 15 columns of data, and need just some of them. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide us with your entire information. Can please tick the answer and vote up if it has helped you?

Comment: I have tested this macro and it seems to work. However, I encountered an issue, which might interfere with my expected results. I extended the data from body, however it seems that there is a limit for elements there. I would need a lot of data to enter there (I have to send values from about 13 columns, and add two phrases, one at the start and one or two at the end. Any idea how can I pass through that limitation?

Comment: That's odd. So basically, you want to add data from the 13 columns to the body of the e-mail. Can you supply me with the error message and the 13 columns content for one line?

Comment: The error is: "Compile error: Expected: label or statement or end of statement". This issue occurs when having a lot of characters between quotation marks and if I have a lot of items on the body line. I updated the question, adding the code you provided added and modified by me. When having this error, it makes the whole body line red. Any idea what might cause this and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have compile errors. I've edited the correct `.body` in my answer now.

Comment: It works perfectly!!! @JLILI Aman Thank you! I accepted your code as answer. Could you just please let me know what the underscore means? It splits the body content due to limitation on one line?

Comment: A space followed by an underscore tells VBA or (VB.NET) IDE that the current statement isn't finished yet but continues on the next line.